# Create time series in R starting 10/1/2019 to 12/30/2019 not including weekends or holidays

Tags: r, time, series

I am trying to create a time series using the ts() function. My data set has 63 values with the starting date as 10-01-2019 and the last date as 12-31-2019. This data set skips weekends and holidays. I am trying this:

```
ts(data, start = c(2019,10), end = c(2019, 12), frequency = 260)
```

since there are 260 days a year not including weekends, but that isn't working. I keep getting a time series with the wrong number of observations (there should still be 63 values right?) I am confused with how to set this up. If anyone could help me, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!!

Comment: Take a look at the [timeDate](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/timeDate/versions/3043.102) package, where you can specify your weekdays and holiday calendar. `ts` is for regular time series only, so it can't handle weekends and holidays.

Answer (score 0):

`ts` is normally used for monthly, quarterly and annual data, not daily data.  If you want to do it anyways you can use `ts(data)` which will use an index of 1, 2, etc. Using `data` in the Note at the end:

```
ts(data)
## Time Series:
## Start = 1 
## End = 3 
## Frequency = 1 
## [1] 1 2 3
```

If you have a `Date` class vector `d` the same length as `data` you can use zoo or xts and either use that or convert it to `ts` using `as.ts` like this (where the index is the number of days since the UNIX Epoch).  If you want to specify a frequency you can add a frequency= argument to the zoo call.

```
library(zoo)
z <- zoo(data, d)
z
## 2019-10-01 2019-10-03 2019-10-04 
##          1          2          3 

as.ts(z)
## Time Series:
## Start = 18170 
## End = 18173 
## Frequency = 1 
## [1]  1 NA  2  3
```

### Note

```
data <- 1:3
d <- as.Date(c("2019-10-01", "2019-10-03", "2019-10-04"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `bizdays` and `timeDate` packages as follows:

```
library(bizdays)
library(timeDate)

create.calendar(name='America/New_York', holidays = as.Date(holidayNYSE(2019)), weekdays = c('saturday', 'sunday'), start.date=as.Date('2019-01-01'), end.date = as.Date('2019-12-31'))

bizseq(as.Date('2019-10-01'), as.Date('2019-12-31'), 'America/New_York')
 [1] "2019-10-01" "2019-10-02" "2019-10-03" "2019-10-04" "2019-10-07" "2019-10-08" "2019-10-09"
 [8] "2019-10-10" "2019-10-11" "2019-10-14" "2019-10-15" "2019-10-16" "2019-10-17" "2019-10-18"
[15] "2019-10-21" "2019-10-22" "2019-10-23" "2019-10-24" "2019-10-25" "2019-10-28" "2019-10-29"
[22] "2019-10-30" "2019-10-31" "2019-11-01" "2019-11-04" "2019-11-05" "2019-11-06" "2019-11-07"
[29] "2019-11-08" "2019-11-11" "2019-11-12" "2019-11-13" "2019-11-14" "2019-11-15" "2019-11-18"
[36] "2019-11-19" "2019-11-20" "2019-11-21" "2019-11-22" "2019-11-25" "2019-11-26" "2019-11-27"
[43] "2019-11-29" "2019-12-02" "2019-12-03" "2019-12-04" "2019-12-05" "2019-12-06" "2019-12-09"
[50] "2019-12-10" "2019-12-11" "2019-12-12" "2019-12-13" "2019-12-16" "2019-12-17" "2019-12-18"
[57] "2019-12-19" "2019-12-20" "2019-12-23" "2019-12-24" "2019-12-26" "2019-12-27" "2019-12-30"
[64] "2019-12-31"
```

There are 64 days in this sequence; your 63 days may be because of differences in the holiday calendar.